# Function (File) Name Collision Warning

Tags: function, matlab, collision

Is there a way to make MATLAB remind a developer or warn a user that *several* conflicting (same name) versions of specific function m-file exists in different directories currently present in the `path`? This would be useful for in large collaborative MATLAB projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a specific function name you need to check to see if any functions with that name already exist, you can use the function [WHICH](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/which.html). For example, if I add a new function file `test.m` to my current directory (`C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\bin\`), then this is what WHICH tells me:

```
>> which test -all
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\bin\test.m
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\stats\stats\@classregtree\test.m  % classregtree method
C:\Users\user\Documents\MATLAB\test.m                                    % Shadowed
```

There are now three functions called `test`: one is a class method for `classregtree` objects, one is the function I just made (top line), and the last (bottom line) is now shadowed by the one I just made. This would mean that, if I called `test` from my current directory, the first one would be called. If I change to another directory, I get this instead:

```
>> which test -all
C:\Users\user\Documents\MATLAB\test.m
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\stats\stats\@classregtree\test.m  % classregtree method
```

The newer `test` function doesn't show up now, since the previous directory wasn't saved on the [MATLAB path](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/br7ppws-1.html). The previously shadowed `test` function would now be the one called.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to check for all possible conflicts within your path, you can use [this function](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/66874-ondrejtichacek-name-collisions) from File Exchange.

The example usage:

```
>> [~, collisions] = name_collisions;
Found the following duplicate names:

 25 x    Contents.m
  2 x    complex2interleaved.m
  2 x    demosinit.m
  2 x    exported_values.mat
  2 x    gcGuiReport.mat
  2 x    header.m
  2 x    interleaved2complex.m
  2 x    ltfatdiditfail.m
  2 x    mexinit.m
  2 x    octinit.m
  2 x    ref_spreadadj_1.m
  2 x    signalsinit.m
  2 x    startup.m
  2 x    testinginit.m
```

It also returns a structure with paths to the colliding files.

```
>> disp(collisions)
  51×1 struct array with fields:

    name
    folder
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum
```